# JWT Authentication with Django REST Framework using otp for getting api tokens

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, jwt

I have a custom user login where, I use mobile OTP verification and not at all using any django user model through out my project.need to authenticate jwt django restframework by otp. please help me with this.
thanks

Comment: you can show your code, what you were trying to do

Answer (score 1):

First send **otp** and **save** this in db.

```
class LoginView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        data = request.data
        response = Response()       
        username = data.get('username', None)
        password = data.get('password', None)
        user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                if user.two_step_verification:

                    GENERATE OTP HERE AND SAVE THIS IN USER MODEL...

                    user.otp = 'YOUR OTP'
                    user.save(update_fields=['otp',]) 
                    
                    SEND OTP HERE...                       
             
                    return Response({"send":"Two step verification OTP successfully send!!!"},status = status.HTTP_200_OK) 
            else:
                return Response({"No active" : "This account is not active!!"},status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        else:
            return Response({"Invalid" : "Invalid username or password!!"},status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

Then verify this.
Here I use `rest_framework_simplejwt`

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken

@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny,])
def two_step_otp_Verify(request,otp):
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(otp = otp,is_active = True)
        verify = 'VERIFY YOUR OTP HERE'
        if verify:
            response = Response()
            user.otp = None
            user.last_login = timezone.now()
            user.save()
            refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
            
            response.set_signed_cookie(
                       key = 'ACCESS_TOKEN', 
                       value = str(refresh.access_token),
                       .....
                       )
            #ORRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
            login(request, user)
            
            response.data = {"Success" : "Login successfully"}
            return response
        else:
            return Response({"Time out" : "Given otp is expired!!"}, status=status.HTTP_408_REQUEST_TIMEOUT)
    except:
        return Response({"No User" : "Invalid otp OR No any active user found for given otp"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```